# Method simulation and Npm

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know how to use Npm in a method simulation.

In a method, I am using an Npm module `slug` to get a slug from the input and set the object's property before inserting it to the mongo.

A simplified version looks like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  submitSomething: function(something) {
    var getSlug = Npm.require('slug');

    something.slug = getSlug(something.property);
    Something.insert(something);
  }
});
```

All works fine on the server side, but Meteor cannot simulate this method for latency compensation because Npm modules are not available on the client side.

How can I make the simluation to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have that library at your client-side, whether using `bower install slug` or include the [library source](https://github.com/dodo/node-slug/blob/master/slug.js) in your HTML document, or store the library source in a **Global** variable, then use it like calling `Slug("some-URL")` in your client-side.

Comment: Are libraries installed with `bower` usable on the server side?

Comment: @MikeC Short answer : no, typically `bower` is for client-side and `npm` is for server-side package management, **at least as far as I know**

Answer (score 0):

Save your time. There is good package for slugs already:

https://atmospherejs.com/ongoworks/speakingurl